# Primitive cast and assignments in Java

Tags: java

I understand why the following is wrong:

```
byte a = 3; 
byte b = 8; 
byte c = a + b;  // compile error
```

It won't compile. Expressions always result in an `int`. So we should have done the explicit cast:

```
byte c = (byte) (a + b);   // valid code
```

But **I don't understand why the following is correct**:

```
byte d = 3 + 8;   // it's valid! why?
```

Because literal integer (such as 3 or 8) is always implicitly an `int`. And `int-or-smaller` expressions always result in an `int` too. Can anybody explain what is going on here?

The only thing I can guess is that the compiler equates this expression to the following:

```
byte d = 11;
```

and doesn't consider this an expression.

Comment: Given the registers are 32-bit or 64-bit, I would wonder why you are using `byte` in the first place.

Comment: `byte c = a + b;`, because it doesn't fit in byte.

Comment: @RongNK: No, that's wrong. It's because `a + b` evaluates to an `int`, and the compiler doesn't permit implicit narrowing conversions of non-constant expressions.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This has *less†* to do with whether or not `3 + 8` is evaluated to `11` at compile-time, and *more* to do with the fact the compiler is explicitly permitted to implicitly narrow `int`s to `byte`s in certain cases. In particular, the language specification explicitly permits implicit narrowing conversions to `byte` of constant expressions of type `int` that can fit in a `byte` at compile-time.

The relevant section of the [JLS here is section §5.2:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type `byte`, `short`,
>   `char`, or `int`:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the
>     variable is `byte`, `short`, or `char`, **and the value of the constant
>     expression is representable in the type of the variable**.
>
> The compile-time narrowing of constants means that code such as:
>   `byte theAnswer = 42;`
>   is allowed. Without the narrowing, the fact that the integer literal `42` has type `int` would
>   mean that a cast to `byte` would be required:

†: Obviously, as per the specification, the constant expression needs to be evaluated to see if it fits in the narrower type or not. **But the salient point is that without this section of the specification, the compiler would not be permitted to make the implicit narrowing conversion**.

Let's be clear here:

```
byte a = 3; 
byte b = 8;
```

The reason that *these* are permitted is because of the above section of the specification. That is, the compiler is allowed to make the implicit narrowing conversion of the literal `3` to a `byte`. It's not because the compiler evaluates the constant expression `3` to its value `3` at compile-time.

Comment: @Paul Bellora: I'm sorry you feel that way; I'm not intending to be combative. Please help me understand how I can come across not that way?

Comment: While your answer is super-helpful, it seems specifically designed to take down the other existing answer. Ideally, they would've simply supported one another, one with examples, the other with JLS citations. I try to keep my downvotes constructive, but in this case I just found the tone very distracting, so I felt like no vote with a comment was a good compromise.

Comment: @Paul Bellora: No, that is not my intention at all, genuinely. :-(

Comment: Okay, maybe I read too much into it then. Thanks for the great explanation.

Comment: +1. This must be why the compiler, instead of just compiling the code, is also doing some calculations.

Comment: Well, the compiler being able to calculate the exact value is *one of the preconditions* to allowing the conversion. So I'd say it has *a lot* to do with this.

Answer (score 41):

> The only thing I can guess is that the compiler equates this expression to the following:

Yes it does. As long as the right side expression is made of **constants** (which fit into the required primitive type -- see @Jason's answer for what the JLS says about this exactly), you can do that. This will not compile because 128 is out of range:

```
byte a = 128;
```

Note that if you transform your first code snippet like this:

```
final byte a = 3; 
final byte b = 8; 
byte c = a + b;
```

it compiles! As your two bytes are `final` *and* their expressions are constants, this time, the compiler can determine that the result will fit into a byte when it is first initialized.

This, however, will not compile:

```
final byte a = 127; // Byte.MAX_VALUE
final byte b = 1;
byte c = a + b // Nope...
```

The compiler will error out with a "possible loss of precision".

Comment: It's not correct. It has nothing to do with whether or not `3 + 8` is evaluated to `11` at compile-time. It's because the language specification clearly states that constants expressions of type `int` that can fit in a `byte` may be implicitly narrowed to `byte` at compile-time.

Comment: @fge: Read what I quoted from the specification. It explicitly states that the value of the constant expression must be re presentable in the narrower type. In bold in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17111090/45914).

Comment: @Jason You missed the "_and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable._" so it is relevant that 3 + 8 evaluates to 11 and not to, say, 128.

Comment: @Jason Can you specifically quote the part of this answer that's incorrect? I'm having trouble following you. "As long as the right side expression is made of constants" seems to be in line with your JLS citation.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel: I missed no such thing. It's in **bold** in my answer.

Comment: @Paul Bellora: Because without the section of the specification that I drew attention to, an explicit cast would be required. It's the section of the specification that I quoted that explicitly permits the implicit narrowing conversion.

Comment: Then I really don't understand what your problem is with this answer.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel: Again, because without the section of the specification that I drew attention to, the compiler would not be permitted to do an implicit narrowing conversion.

Comment: @Jason So your peeve is that fge doesn't reference the JLS?

Comment: @Jason I mentioned it: the compiler "can determine that the result will fit into a byte when it is first initialized"

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel: No, it's not a peeve. What's important here is that the language explicitly permits implicit narrowing conversions. The compiler has to evaluate the constant expression to see if it fits, but without the explicit enabling of implicit narrowing conversions, it wouldn't matter.

Comment: What does `final` have to do with the result?

Comment: @SteveKuo a `final` primitive type variable cannot change value during the JVM's lifetime. The compiler can therefore "retain" the value and, if it is a constant, use that value where this variable is referenced.

Comment: @Steve Kuo: The definition of *constant expression* permits use of simple names that refer to constant variables ([§15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)) and variables that are initialized with constant expressions and are marked `final` are, by definition, constant variables ([§4.12.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)).

Answer (score 1):

### It is because `3` and `8` are **compile time constants.**

Therefore, at the time of compilation happens, compiler can identify that `3 + 8` can fit into a `byte` variable.

If you make your `a` and `b` to final (constant) variable. `a + b` will become a compile time constant. Therefore, it will compile without any issue.

```
    final byte a = 3;
    final byte b = 8;
    byte c = a + b;
```