# Add method in a list

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add a short value to my indices list, but I'm getting an error that the method has invalid arguments.

```
    int verticesStart = vertices.Count();
    short vertStart = (short)verticesStart;
```

Since the indices list is a "short", I cast the variable verticesStart so it is usable.

```
    indices.Add(vertStart + 0);
```

This line is where I get the error. Am I not allowed to do any kind of math function in an Add method?

Comment: What is the type of `indices`?

Comment: short. An index buffer can only be a 16 bit type

Comment: No, I mean `indices`, the thing you're calling `Add` on. I don't know what type of container it is.

Comment: Oh it's just a list of short values that I use for my index buffer

Comment: Your problem is related to the way shorts/integers are added http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343624/integer-summing-blues-short-short-problem/4347752#4347752

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since the indices list is a "`short`"

Therefore, you can only add `short`s to `indices`.

> `vertStart + 0`

The rules of the language specify that `short + int` has type `int`. Since `vertStart` is of type `short` and `0` is an `int` literal, `vertStart + 0` has type `int`. Therefore,

```
indices.Add(vertStart + 0);
```

is attempting to add an `int` to a list that you said holds `short`s. This is not possible.

> Am I not allowed to do any kind of math function in an `Add` method?

That is not the point. Any expressions are evaluated for their values before they are passed along to the `Add` method. In your case, you have an expression that evaluates to type `int`. But if `indicies` is really a `List<short>` as you say, then you can't add `int`s to it. You will have to have a narrowing conversion to `short`.

```
indices.Add((short)(vertStart + 0));
```

Comment: This worked. I had forgotten that any plain number is an int. Thank you

Comment: This answer is incorrect, in that it implies that if you had two `short`s and added them together, the answer would be a `short`. In fact, it's an `int`. Also, `0` is a literal, which normally (e.g. `var x = 0;`) resolves to `int`, but it is more flexible; e.g. `short s = 1;` is valid, though `int i = 1; short s = i;` is not. Curiouser, `const int i = 1; short s = i;` is valid (since the compiler is able to understand the second part as `short s = 1;`).

Comment: @Tim S.: It implies no such thing. And while what you say about `short`s is true, they are not relevant to this question.

Comment: Well, I guess you're right, it technically does not. However, I interpreted that from it, and others might do the same. I'm afraid my downvote is already locked in, though, so I can't undo that (unless you edit it).

Comment: @Tim S.: I've edited. Regarding your curiosity, the C# language specification permits implicit narrowing conversions from constant expressions of type `int` that are representable in the narrower type. There was a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17110918/45914) about Java recently, but the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110918/primitive-cast-and-assignments-in-java/17111090#17111090) is basically the same for C#.

Comment: @Tim S.: The relevant section of the C# specification is §7.19 which says: "*An implicit constant expression conversion (§6.1.9) permits a constant expression of type `int` to be converted to `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `uint`, or `ulong`, provided the value of the constant expression is within the range of the destination type*."

Answer (score 3):

Arithmetic in C# is defined for 32-bit and up integer types, not for `short`. When you do `vertStart + 0`, the result is an `int`, that you have to cast back to a `short`:

```
indices.Add((short)(vertStart + 0));
```

(I'm assuming you're not actually adding `0`, but some other value. Because adding 0, of course, doesn't change the value.)

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetic is always done on at least `int`. So when you do that addition (why add 0, if I may ask?) you're going to get an `int` back. You'd have to cast back to short afterwards again.

Comment: Eh crap. The list indices is used to store information into my index buffer, but I can only store a 16 bit value in the buffer so using an int isn't an option

Answer (score -2):

Using this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<short> list = new List<short>();
        list.Add(1+1);
    }
}
```

In C#, the 1 will be `int` so you need to make sure you add variables of `short`